# Google cloud storage: gsutil cp -n doesn't "skip existing" or display files being uploaded

Tags: google-cloud-storage, cp, gsutil

When resuming an upload (already about 2GB, 2,000 files was uploaded out of 40Gb, 7,000 files) `cp` doesn't display a list of "skipping existing files" as it used too. Also the gsutil message  `[xx/7.3k files][xx MiB/ 40GiB]` doesn't start where it left of when stopped (ei: `[2k/7.3k files][2GiB/ 40GiB]`) but it starts from scratch : `[00/7.3k files][00 MiB/ 40GiB]`.

I checked the upload on `https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser` : nothing seems strange, new files are being uploaded and the ones sent yesterday are still there. So why gsutil doesn't say that there is already 2GiB and 2k files online?

Also the `cp` command doesn't display the files it's currently uploading as it used to. Any idea why? (the rsync does though)

This is my cp command `gsutil -m cp -r -n "MyLocalFolder" gs://my_bucket/Backup`
Also I didn't modify my local folder, nor the files it contains.

---

Another problem I am running into is that the `-m rsync -r` command tries to upload already existing files instead of skipping them.  For debugging I switched several times between the `cp` and `rsync` command and the `rsync` doesn't fully take in account what the `cp` command has already uploaded: it keeps uploading existing files.  So is there different checksum for `cp` and `rsync`? If not how can this behavior be explained?

**Solution for this second problem**: 
In fact I was using the same target for cp and rsync but there are not built the same way:
If the cp command is `gsutil -m cp -r -n "MyLocalFolder" gs://my_bucket/Backup` then the rsync command is `gsutil -m rsync -r "MyLocalFolder" gs://my_bucket/Backup/MyLocalFolder`

Comment: I posted an answer, but if you see something that you think is a bug, can you create a simple folder and set of commands that reproduce it and send mail to gs-team@google.com?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gsutil cp -n` still needs to discover which files in your local folder that it needs to upload (as the folder's contents may have changed), so if you repeat the command and there are some existing files in the destination bucket, it still needs to enumerate the local files even if it is going to skip them.  That's why it doesn't start out at something like `[2k / 7.3k files] [2GiB / 40GiB]` .

It should still output "`Skipping existing item`" for items that already exist, though.

`rsync` uses the same checksumming logic as cp, so I suspect you are not uploading files to the exact same destination.

`gsutil` version 4.21 changed both the `cp` and `rsync` commands to display summary information instead of individual progress prints for each file, which tended to print an overwhelming amount of information to the terminal, particularly when the `-m` flag was used.

Comment: Yes, it's logical that it doesn't start out,  right when I launch it, at `[2k / 7.3k files] [2GiB / 40GiB]` but to my understanding, it should after a while (the time to enumerate the local and distant file) display `[2k / 7.3k files] [2GiB / 40GiB]`. I don't get this, at the most, after a couple of minutes I get : `[0k / 7.3k files] [100MB / 40GiB]` (maybe the files which were in the process of being uploaded when I stop gsutil).

Comment: Also for the rsync,  I am uploading to the same location (I use the same command, I  am only replacing the `-m cp -r -n` by `-m rsync -r` so the local and distant locations remain unchanged). If I got you correctly, the normal behavior of gsutil 4.21 for cp and rsync would be  to display (in my case) 2000 lines of skipping items and then only this line which is regularly updated (ei, `[2k / 7.3k files] [2GiB / 40GiB]`, then `3k / 7.3k files] [2.1GiB / 40GiB]`...). Is that correct?

Comment: That's somewhat correct, it will skip items as they are enumerated, so you'll arrive at 2000 skipped lines eventually.  I think if you need more debugging details we should work with a reproducible example.